# Repeater won't let me access controls like buttons, dropdown, etc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, repeater

I'm using a repeater `ListOfArticles` and have controls inside it like `ddlSizes` and `btnSelectArticle`. Normally you can just double click the control and in the aspx.vb page you can specify an action. I have heard something about Findcontrol, but can't figure out or find much information that I understand. I don't want to sound like an ass, but I would really prefer help for the aspx.vb page and not in C# or Javascript.

An example of what I'm trying to do is, once you've clicked `btnSelectArticle` the label `lblSelection` receives the following values `Amount: txtAmount - Size: ddlSizes.SelectedValue`.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListOfArticles" runat="server" DataSourceID="objdsArticleList">

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSizes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="objdsSizes"  DataTextField="SizeName" DataValueField="SizeID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSizes_SelectedIndexChanged" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btnSelect_OnClick" />

<asp:Label ID="lblSelection" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

In the aspx.vb page I can only select this and my controls like `ddlSizes` and `btnSelect` aren't recognized.

```
Protected Sub rptListOfArticles_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rptListOfArticles.ItemCommand
End Sub
```

Any help towards a solution would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use the FindControl method to find the specific control in the selected repeater Item.

so an example would be (within the ItemCommand method)

```
Dim lblSelection as Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblSelection"), Label)
lblSelection.Text = "Your Text"
```

Edit **
To Answer your questions in the comments:

Yes to access the SelectedValue of the ddlSize DropDown you will need to create this:

```
Dim ddlSize As DropDownList = Ctype(e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList)
```

The Repeater will know when to call this method when any Buttons are Clicked within the Repeater. Add a CommandName to your buttons so that you can then control what happens in the ItemCommand method.

e.g.

```
<asp:Button id="btnDoSomething" runat="server" text="Run ItemCommand" CommandName="Command1" />
```

In the ItemCommand use the code:

```
If e.CommandName = "Command1" Then
    ' run your code
End If
```

Comment: so if I were to have `lblSelection.Text` = `ddlSize.SelectedValue` I would need to make a `Dim ddlSize as Dropdown`?

Comment: yup!absolutely you have to make the control object in code behind and initialize it using e.findcontrol

Comment: and how does the repeater know when its called upon? Like when I click the button btnSelect, how does it know to pull the function?

Comment: in the itemCommand, do you mean if e.CommandName and not ItemCommand?

Comment: WOOT you're a life saver Tim :)

Comment: EXTRA: If I wanted to do the same for a dropdownlist, in the aspx page add `OnSelectedIndexChanged = "ddlChanged"` and in the aspx.vb page `if e.CommandName = "ddlChanged"`?

Comment: For this you will need to get the Index of the Repeater Item in which the DropDownList resides and then find the controls within this RepeaterItem. Probably best start a new question for this, or give it a google search first.

Comment: Well I tried this with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061857/dropdownlist-in-a-repeater-selected-index-changed-not-working, nothing really useful came out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the event of dropdownlist in ItemCommand Event. Event bubbling concept comes here actually the child control bubble the evenet up to its parent i.e repeater control so you can handle it in parent control event eventually
 for  more details [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater_events.aspx) you will have indepth insight of all events of repeater